# Under IOS5, using ARC while creating my own delegate, error regarding using _weak

Tags: ios5, delegates, automatic-ref-counting

In my .h file I have this:

```
@protocol ScanBookDelegate
- (void)MethodNameToCallBack:(NSArray *)s;
@end

@property (nonatomic, weak) id  <ScanBookDelegate> delegate;
```

In my .m file I have:

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

I get this error:

```
Existing ivar 'delegate' for __weak property 'delegate' must be __weak
```

How do I resolve this error?

I am returning an `NSArray *` as I am returning data from a JSON result.

**UPDATE:**

Here is my entire .h file -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ScanBookDelegate
- (void)MethodNameToCallBack:(NSArray *)s;
@end

@interface jabBookScan : NSObject
<NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
{
    NSURLConnection *internalConnection;
    NSMutableData *container;
    id <ScanBookDelegate> delegate;
}
- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)req;
- (void)start;
- (NSMutableData *) lookupBook:(NSString *) isbn;
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSURLRequest *request;
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^completionBlock)(id obj, NSError *err);
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *jsonRootObject;
@property NSMutableData *responseData;
@property NSURL *myURL;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id  <ScanBookDelegate> delegate; 
@end
```

Comment: Do you have a delegate already defined elsewhere, say in a superclass?

Comment: @atticus - I was under the impression that the protocol is defining the delegate.  The .h and .m file above are for the same class, as I refer to the protocol in the property, and try to synthesize it, and then I get the error.

Comment: It sounds like the error implies that an ivar has been created as __strong, and that the declaration of the property as 'weak' is problematic. Would you mind posting the entire .h file?

Comment: @atticus - I will do that when I get home, but these lines are the only places where delegate is used.

Comment: @atticus - I put the entire .h file up

Comment: Philippe called it. I suspected you might have been defining the ivar as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of `id <ScanBookDelegate> delegate;` in your {} (at the top) and it should work. You don't need to specify that when using properties. If you really want to, then you can declare that ivar __weak so it matches your property (ivars are strong by default).